# What are the top movies in this Redis sorted set?

Tags: redis

I've downloaded the movies from IMDB (movies-list) from here: http://www.imdb.com/interfaces

I want to count how often a given movie appears in the list with help of Redis sorted sets, but I am bit confused of the outcome:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zrangebyscore 'movies:title' 5000 +inf WITHSCORES
 1) "Countdown"
 2) "5254"
 3) "The Bold and the Beautiful"
 4) "5322"
 5) "Days of Our Lives"
 6) "5451"
 7) "Neighbours"
 8) "6442"
 9) "The New Price Is Right"
10) "7633"
11) "Coronation Street"
12) "8097"
```

I would like to have the movie that appears most often at the top. Also, I am bit confused by the score. What does this 5k, 6k, 7k mean?

The script I use for my experiment is a Rake task like this:

```
  task :import do
    file = File.new(ENV['file'])
    redis = Redis.new
    file.each_line do |l|
      if l =~ /^"(.*)"/
        puts $1
        redis.zincrby 'movies:title', 1, $1
      end
    end
```

Comment: Hm. Redis is right of course:  cat db/movies_utf.txt | grep "Days of Our Lives" | wc
 -->   5462    --> The problem is thus in the data set.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using zrevrangebyscore instead of zrangebyscore.

Syntax:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE key max min [WITHSCORES] [LIMIT offset count]
```

For example, in your case:

```
zrangebyscore 'movies:title' +inf 5000 WITHSCORES
```

[Reference](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore)